# How can I get mod_rewrite to ignore certain directories and all their subdirectories?

Tags: mod-rewrite, symphony-cms

I'm using Symphony CMS which as default has a mod_rewrite that rewrites all directories.

However, I need it to ignore the directories `test` and `transfer` and all their subdirectories.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157/htaccess-directives-to-not-redirect-certain-urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a new .htacess access files in each of your two directories, and then place the following in:

mod_rewrite off

That should sort it.

Answer (score 1):

Put this rule above the others:

```
RewriteRule ^(test|transfer)(/|$) - [L]
```